# Background Image Swap On MouseOver For Unorderd List Items

Tags: html

I have a list items and I want to have an image on the items instead of a text....
What is the best way to do it? and what is killing me is trying to swap the image with onmouseover event...
Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuS6Y/)

Explanation:

Here you give a background image to each `<li>` element and than you give a little padding to these `<li>`... now using `:hover` you replace these with another image :)

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>Hello</li>
   <li>World</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
ul li {
    background-image: url('http://www.bseindia.com/include/images/nav_bullet.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 4px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

li:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.rbs.in/India/_image/bullet-blue.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 2px 4px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

​

Comment: Thank you... But I need to change the whole li images, i don't want to write text in it, the whole li is an image...

Comment: than simply do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/tuS6Y/1/ and remove the text if you want

Comment: This is great! but I want every bullet to have it's own different image.

Comment: than you need to use CSS `:nth-child()` and you should mark this answer as correct so that others can refer this

Comment: Can you give me an Examlpe Please.

Comment: @user1744509 http://jsfiddle.net/tuS6Y/2/

Comment: It works but the image changes when the mouse comes over the ul not just over the il it self.